# Assign value to ng-model via radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I'm new to Angular JS so mind my mistakes. I am trying to assign a value to an ng-model through dynamically created radio buttons. So far, this is what I have:

```
<div data-ng-init="radio=['Core','Software Development','Systsmes Analysis','All']">
    <div data-ng-repeat="r in radio">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" data-ng-model="types" data-ng-value="types='{{r}}'" name="type" id="{{r}}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{r}}">
                {{r}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>You chose {{types}}</p>
</div>
```

I am able to output the radio buttons as seen here:

[image: What I have done]

But I am unable to output the selected radio buttons value.

What I want achieve is something like this:

[image: What I want to achieve]

Where the selected radio button's value pop's up in "You have chosen x".

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an object with dot notation:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.radio = { type: '' }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-init="radio=['Core','Software Development','Systems Analysis','All']">
    <div ng-repeat="r in radio">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="{{r}}" type="radio" ng-model="radio.type" ng-value="'{{r}}'" name="type">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{r}}">{{r}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>You chose {{radio.type}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```